# Python - If statments not working in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new here, and to python also.. The if statments in the following code are not running. does anyone know why? This is a camel game I need to submit by sunday.

```
import random
from Tkinter import *

print "Welcome to Camel!"
print "You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi desert."
print "The natives want their camel back",
print "and are chasing you down! Survive your"
print "desert trek and out run the natives."
print ""

summ = 0
done = False
miles = 0
thirst = 0
tiredness = 0
distance = 20
drinks = 3

window = Tk()
window.title("Camel")

def A():
global drinks
if drinks > 0:
drinks -= 1
thirst = 0
else:
print "You ran out of drinks!"
done = True

def B():
global summ, thirst, tiredness, distance
miles = random.randint(5, 12)
summ += miles
print "miles traveled: ", miles
print "Total miles traveled: ", summ
print ""
thirst += 1
tiredness += 1
distance -= random.randint(7, 14)
distance += miles

def C():
global summ, thirst, tiredness, distance
miles = random.randint(10, 20)
summ += miles
print "Miles traveled: ", miles
print "Total miles traveled: ", summ
print ""
thirst += 1
tiredness += random.randint(1, 3)
distance -= random.randint(7, 14)
distance += miles

def D():
global distance
tiredness = 0
print "Your Camel is happy."
print ""
distance -= random.randint(7, 14)

def E():
print "Total miles traveled: ", summ
print "Drinks in canteen: ", drinks
print "The natives are %i miles behind you." % (distance)
print ""

def Q():
exit()


A = Button(window, text = "A. Drink from your canteen.", command = A)
B = Button(window, text = "B. Ahead moderate speed.", command = B)
C = Button(window, text = "C. Ahead full speed.", command = C)
D = Button(window, text = "D. Stop for the night.", command = D)
E = Button(window, text = "E. Status check.", command = E)
Q = Button(window, text = "Q. Quit.", command = Q)
A.pack()
B.pack()
C.pack()
D.pack()
E.pack()
Q.pack()

if thirst > 4 and thirst <= 6:
print "You are thirsty."
print ""
elif thirst > 6:
print "You died of thirst!"
done = True
if tiredness > 5 and tiredness <= 8 and done != True:
print "Your camel is getting tired."
print ""
elif tiredness > 8 and done == False:
print "Your camel is dead."
done = True

if distance <= 0 and done != True:
print "The natives caught you."
done = True
elif distance < 15 and done != True:
print "The natives are getting close!"

if summ >= 200 and done == False:
print "You won!"
done = True

if random.randint(1, 100) <= 5 and done != True:
print "You found an oasis!"
print ""
thirst = 0
tiredness = 0
drinks = 3

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're supposed to provide a [mcve] by pasting it here for the issue you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm gonna put as much effort into this answer as you did put into the question: Maybe the problem is that there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: We have no idea what you mean by "the if statements are not running".

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. As posted, it's impossible to run your code. Also, you should remove any code not strictly necessary to reproduce the problem. If the problem is with a `if` statement, you only need a single `if` statement and just enough code to show it not working.

Comment: Are you aware that all of the `if` statements immediately before `window.mainloop()` will execute before the window shows up, and before the user has the ability to click on any buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that these are the if statements that you speak of:

```
if thirst > 4 and thirst <= 6:
   print "You are thirsty."
   print ""
elif thirst > 6:
   print "You died of thirst!"
   done = True
if tiredness > 5 and tiredness <= 8 and done != True:
   print "Your camel is getting tired."
   print ""
elif tiredness > 8 and done == False:
   print "Your camel is dead."
   done = True

if distance <= 0 and done != True:
   print "The natives caught you."
   done = True
elif distance < 15 and done != True:
   print "The natives are getting close!"

if summ >= 200 and done == False:
  print "You won!"
  done = True

if random.randint(1, 100) <= 5 and done != True:
  print "You found an oasis!"
  print ""
  thirst = 0
  tiredness = 0
  drinks = 3
```

Your if statements are running, but they are only running at the beginning of the code because they are not in a function or a loop, they are only being run at the very start of your code.

if you are using if statements or any loops and such, you need to indent what is inside them using the tab key. if you want to have something inside an if statement and a loop or something of that sort, you do tab twice. These are to tell python where your loops and comparisons end. If you do not indent at all, python will think that there is nothing inside the loop. You also need to indent with functions, if you want to put the if statements inside of the loop you need to indent it likewise.
Here is and example:

```
while something1 == something2:
   if anotherthing1 == anotherthing2:
      print "something happened"
      somethinghappened = True
```

That is just an example, implement it the way you need to.

Comment: Is this a better answer?

Comment: I think that this is more of what was asked of though

Comment: Is this useful Yishai Lerner?

Comment: you need to first make a loop so that it can run over and over, I am going to update my answer to explain

Comment: if this helps, press the little check button near the star to tell people that it works.

Comment: Yishai, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

put it in a loop and indent the if statements correctly